# systeminfo output from all windows variants

Tags: scripting, operating-system

can someone please point me at documentation that shows the output from the systeminfo command line tool that display windows info please?

on my windows xp machine i get this

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows XP Professional
OS Version:                5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
```

its the **OS name** part i need to know for as many versions of windows as possible
as i would like to create a script which perfoms audit function on all windows versions and some of the commands i use are version specific.

Unless there is a better way to disocver the windows version than using systeminfo

i do not want to use wmi, or .net, i am trying to keep things a slightweight and as simple as possible.

thanks for listening

Cheers

DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get the information you need from the registry, accessible from the command line through the "reg" command or through powershell.  More discussion: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31845351/reliable-way-to-get-windows-version.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an easier way to test for Windows versions in a .bat script:

```
@REM -- .bat script code for detecting various windows versions
@REM h/t to Paul Cramer and Rob van der Woude
@REM http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ver.php (or webcitation.org/6CTMCq12q)

@echo on
if '%OS%' == '' goto win9x
if '%COMSPEC%' == 'C:\COMMAND.COM' goto win9x
ver | find "Windows XP" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto WinXP
ver | find "Vista" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto winVistaOrSvr2008
ver | find "6.0." >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto winVistaOrSvr2008
ver | find "6.1." >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto Win7
ver | find "6.2.9200" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto Win8orSvr2012
ver | find "6." >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto Win8or7orVista
ver | find "Windows 2000" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto win2K
ver | find "Windows 98" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto win9x
ver | find "Windows 95" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto win9x
ver | find "Windows Me" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 goto win9x
@echo **** Sorry, this script does not support your OS version.  This is:
@ver
@goto xit

...

:xit
ver | find "6.1.7600" >nul
@if not errorlevel 1 echo **** Warning! This computer lacks Win7 SP1 ****
ver | find "6.0.6000" >nul
@if not errorlevel 1 echo **** Warning! This computer lacks Vista SP1 and SP2 ****
ver | find "6.0.6001" >nul
@if not errorlevel 1 echo **** Warning! This computer might lack Vista SP2 ****
:xit2
```